# Building a tree from string input

Tags: java, tree, binary-tree, user-input, traversal

I am stuck at the logic as for how to generate a tree when a string input is provided . Such as when i have a input of following form -

(1 (2 (3) (4)) (5 (6) ())

Representing tree will be like so -

```
            1
           / \
          2   5
         / \  /\
         3 4 6 ()
```

I can build tree from usual like tree.add(data) and then looking for the new node to be self added by judging if its greater or smaller than parent node . But i am not able to understand how to implement how to store above the above mention string in binary data structure form.

Here's what i have tried so far -

```
public class BinaryTree {

static Node root;

public static void levelorder(Node<?> n) {
    Queue<Node<?>> nodequeue = new LinkedList<Node<?>>();
    if (n != null)
        nodequeue.add(n);
    while (!nodequeue.isEmpty()) {
        Node<?> next = nodequeue.remove();
        System.out.print(next.data + " ");
        if (next.getLeft() != null) {
            nodequeue.add(next.getLeft());
        }
        if (next.getRight() != null) {
            nodequeue.add(next.getRight());
        }
    }
}

private static String[] breakString(String elements) {
    int indexOfOpenBracket = elements.indexOf("(");
    int indexOfLastBracket = elements.lastIndexOf(")");
    String removedPString = elements.substring(indexOfOpenBracket + 1,
            indexOfLastBracket);
    String[] breakRemovedPString = removedPString.split(" ");
    if (breakRemovedPString[1].contains("(")) {
        add(breakRemovedPString[0], breakRemovedPString[1], breakRemovedPString[2]);
    }
    return breakRemovedPString;
}

static void add(String parent, String leftString, String rightString) {

    Node<String> nodeToAdd = new Node<String>(parent);
    if (root == null) {
        root = nodeToAdd;
        root.left = new Node<String>(leftString);
        root.right = new Node<String>(rightString);
    } else {

    }

}

public static void main(final String[] args) {

    String treeString = "(1 (2) (3))";

    breakString(treeString);

    levelorder(root);
    System.out.println();
 }
}
```

Please suggest some implementation for this problem.

Comment: You must use an additional data structure to parse and evaluate your `String` like a stack.

Comment: Use queue data structure see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: @OzanDeniz I find it interesting how to use a queue in a case like this. I have only solved these exercises using stacks. Mind to provide an answer, so I can learn too? Note: this comment is not meant for trolling.

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza , If you can share more detail or perhaps implimentaion  on this as you have solved this kind of exercise before , that will be really helpful.

Comment: yep you are right. it is built by using stacks. I just wanted to give a starting point. I have not implemented yet but maybe it can be built by using priority queues but i know that is not the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classical parsing problem.  The simplest approach is probably recursive descent.  Here is a grammar for the tree language:

```
T -> ( number T T )
   | ( number )
   | ()
```

To turn this into a parser, we can go through a formal transformation to LL(1) form and then code. I'll let you read up on that and show what results.

```
package treereader;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.Reader;

enum Token { LPAREN, RPAREN, NUMBER, EOF, ERROR };

class Scanner {

    final Reader in;
    final char [] buf = new char[1];
    final StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();

    private static final char EOF_MARK = Character.MIN_VALUE;

    Scanner(Reader in) {
        this.in = in;
        read();
    }

    final void read() {
        try {
            if (in.read(buf) < 1) {
                buf[0] = EOF_MARK;
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("i/o error");
            buf[0] = EOF_MARK;
        }
    }

    Token getNext() {
        while (Character.isWhitespace(buf[0])) {
            read();
        }
        if (Character.isDigit(buf[0])) {
            token.setLength(0);
            do {
                token.append(buf[0]);
                read();
            } while (Character.isDigit(buf[0]));
            return Token.NUMBER;
        }
        if (buf[0] == '(') {
            read();
            return Token.LPAREN;
        }
        if (buf[0] == ')') {
            read();
            return Token.RPAREN;
        }
        if (buf[0] == EOF_MARK) {
            return Token.EOF;
        }
        return Token.ERROR;
    }

    String getString() {
        return token.toString();
    }
}

class Node {
    public void print(PrintStream out) {
        out.print("()");
    }
}

class UnaryNode extends Node {

    int val;

    public UnaryNode(int val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    @Override
    public void print(PrintStream out) {
        out.print("(" + val + ")");
   }
}

class BinaryNode extends Node {

    int val;
    Node left, right;

    public BinaryNode(int val, Node left, Node right) {
        this.val = val;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    @Override
    public void print(PrintStream out) {
        out.print("(" + val + " ");
        left.print(out);
        out.print(' ');
        right.print(out);
        out.print(')');
    }
}

class Parser {

    final Scanner scanner;
    Token lookAhead;

    Parser(Reader in) {
        scanner = new Scanner(in);
        lookAhead = scanner.getNext();
    }

    void advance() {
        lookAhead = scanner.getNext();
    }

    void match(Token token) throws IOException {
        if (lookAhead == token) {
            advance();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Expected " + token + ", found " + lookAhead);
        }
    }

    Node parse() throws IOException {
        Node tree;
        match(Token.LPAREN);
        if (lookAhead == Token.NUMBER) {
            int val = Integer.valueOf(scanner.getString());
            advance();
            if (lookAhead == Token.LPAREN) {
                Node left = parse();
                Node right = parse();
                tree = new BinaryNode(val, left, right);
            } else {
                tree = new UnaryNode(val);
            }
        } else {
            tree = new Node();
        }
        match(Token.RPAREN);
        return tree;
    }
}

public class TreeReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Parser parser = new Parser(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(args[0]))));
            Node tree = parser.parse();
            tree.print(System.out);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you please imperilment this solution , its really hard to understand.

Comment: Thank you @Gene , now can spend my time on understanding this logic.

Comment: @BeingCoder  This is very standard stuff.  Google "recursive descent" and "LL(1) grammar" and you will see many, many materials on line.  I won't duplicate all that here.  Try to lay hands on a good compiler design book.  Aho Sethi and Ullman "Compiler Design" is the standard reference because it is very good.